# How to view the table structure in workbench in mysql database without quotes

Tags: mysql-workbench

I need to view the structure (i.e. table scripts without quotes) of tables from MySQL Workbench.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the DDL via the context menu for an object. So, right click on e.g. your table and let it send the DDL to your current editor or to the clipboard:

[image]

Comment: Its little weird. There is no cleaner way to show table structure?

Comment: Not in a concise way. But you can use the schema tree to inspect sub elements. Expand the tree node and you will find nodes for columns, indexes etc.

Comment: I tried to use Workbench instead of PhpMyAdmin but this is not much user friendly. In PhpMyAdmin I can see colums its data types, ranges, is null, indexes, ... on one page. I need it quite often.

Comment: Oh I have it. I can right click on table name in schema inspector and then click table inspector. There are tables with columns definitions and indexes. It take a little time but there it is.

Answer (score 0):

R click on table name then click Table inspector. It shows table like columns, indexes, triggers, foreign keys, ... All structure info about table.
[image]